# Onedrive API error after MS did OneDrive update last night

Tags: c#, api, onedrive

The code:

```
var stream=await this.oneDriveClient.Drive.Items[itemid].Content.Request().GetAsync();
```

Has been running fine for weeks but stopped working after the Onedrive update last night.
It is throwing exception 'Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException' when we try to download files using the API, file uploads still work. We are also getting the "ItemNotFound" error code.

Below is the exception message and stack trace.

```
ex.Message: Exception of type 'Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException' was thrown.
ex.StackTrace: 
   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.<SendAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendRequestAsync>d__34.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
  at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendStreamRequestAsync>d__33.MoveNext()
-- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at TMSPro.Shared_Objects.ucOneDriveBrowser.<btnDownload_Click>d__5f.MoveNext() in c:\Working\TMSPro_VS2012\TMSPro\Shared_Objects\ucOneDriveBrowser.cs:line 1083
```

Comment: Can you use Fiddler (or something equivalent) to grab the calls being made to the service? We need to see what response is being returned to help.

Comment: details of exception?  Microsoft Graph is kinda like an API access wrapper to get at Microsoft Web-based APIs.  Exceptions like `ServiceException` usually have the exact details of what went wrong (usually access/connect errors).  Without that detail we'd just be guessing.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with Authentication.  This code seems to fix it:

```
  var adalAuthProvider = new AdalAuthenticationProvider(
                    this.AadClientId,
                    this.AadReturnUrl);

            this.oneDriveClient = new OneDriveClient(this.AadTargetUrl + "/_api/v2.0", adalAuthProvider, new HttpProvider(new HttpClientHandler { AllowAutoRedirect = true }, true));
            authTask = adalAuthProvider.AuthenticateUserAsync(this.AadTargetUrl);

            try
            {
                await authTask;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing exactly the same issue. When checking Fiddler, it seems that the response that is returned is a web page with the message: "Sorry something went wrong. Sorry you cannot access this document. ... Correlation ID: 072abf9d-7097-3000-a357-3f21c379dac7 ..."
The Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException has an error code: ItemNotFound.

This was working for ages, and now suddenly stopped working.

Comment: One small addition: in my scenario, I'm using the OneDriveSdk for uploading and downloading files from Sharepoint Online

Comment: Which SDK are you using?  We are using the C#/.Net SDK.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue in the OneDrive for Business service that has since been resolved. We apologize for the inconvenience, and have taken steps to minimize the chances of similar failures in the future.